# Как посчитать элементы на Html - странице с помощью selenium?

Tags: python, html

Есть следующий код html. Необходимо посчитать элементы **td** (В данном случае их 16). Как лучше реализовать?

```
<table class ='table'>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td class = '1'></td>
     <td class = '1'></td>
     <td class = '1'></td>
     <td class = '1'></td>
   </tr>
   <tr> ... </tr>
   <tr> ... </tr>
   <tr> ... </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Думаю, может реализовать через xpath? Например, как он выглядит для 5 и 6 элемента: .../table/tbody/tr[**2**]/td[**1**] и .../table/tbody/tr[**2**]/td[**2**]

Comment: а просто len(html.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, "td")) не даст количество td из всего html?

Comment: @Jack_oS  Пока не могу глянуть, позже проверю. Этот вариант не подойдет, если появятся элементы td в другой части страницы, которые мне не нужно считать. Но только что нашел: browser.find_element_by_class_name('1').length - возможно подойдет, т.к класс уникальный.

Comment: В данном случае лучше использовать bs4.